# Is a bag of 6x4x2 (inches) dimensions 3-1-1 compliant?

Tags: hand-luggage, tsa

It's a clear plastic bag, I am not sure how to translate 1 quart to dimensions. I've seen 1 quart bags on Amazon, and they're all of varying dimensions.

Comment: A quart is a measure of volume. One US quart is equal to 57¾ cubic inches (note that this is much smaller than the Imperial quart).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [TSA](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/liquids-rule) does not specify the exact size of the bag to be used, as long as it is less than one quart (946 ml or just under 1 liter).  TSA agents are unlikely to pull out a ruler to meausre your bag, so as long as it is obvious that the bag contains less than one quart you should be fine.

For reference, the [UK](https://www.gov.uk/hand-luggage-restrictions) and [Australian](http://travelsecure.infrastructure.gov.au/onboard/liquids-aerosols-and-gels.aspx) governments (which have similar restrictions on liquids) use 20 cm x 20 cm (when laid flat) as a rule of thumb.

Answer (score 3):

According to [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=6+inches+*+4+inches+*+2+inches+in+quarts), this is slightly less than a quart.

> (6 inches) * (4 inches) * (2 inches) =
>   0.831168831 US quarts